# How to pay comingled personal and business credit card charges for small corporation

Tags: credit-card, credit

If I used my personal credit card for a business expense, may I pay that portion of the credit card bill with a business account check?

Answer (score 6):

Better pay with your own check, and expense to the business.

Comment: Agreed, better yet, get a separate card for biz.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I agree with this but I have seen that at times your individual credit worthiness and access to capital can FAR exceed the businesses' access to capital. Making providing equipment and expenses only practical to pay from a personal card, with the calculated risk the business will earn it back, but the business would be unable to float a balance the same size.

Comment: @CQM excellent point. How about choosing one personal card, and using that card only for business? From a paper trail standpoint, this would serve to keep things separate.

Comment: @Joe this is fine for a disregarded business (LLC/soleprop), but I don't think that would be passing well for a corp